# Removing events from elements .each vs. .unbind in jQuery... what's the difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In a script I'm writing, I've noticed there are two currently working ways to 'unbind' an event from an element.

```
$("elementName").each( function() { $(this).unbind('click'); });
```

And This way...

```
$("elementName").unbind('click'); });
```

I know `.each` loops through the elements but the second scripts appears to work just as well. So what am I missing, why use `.each`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to use [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) in this case. Most jQuery functions are intended to work on groups of matched elements so `$("elementName").unbind('click')` is best way to apply [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to multiple elements at once; however, if you like typing you could use the `.each` iterator and do them one a time.

Generally you'll use `.each` when you want to do something different to some or all of the matched elements. For example:

```
$('a').each(function(i) { $(this).addClass('pancakes' + i) });
```

would add a different class to each `<a>` and would be an appropriate use of `.each`. Or an `unbind` example:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.data('where-is') == 'pancakes-house')
        $this.unbind('click');
    // Yes, there are other ways to do this, this is just an illustrative example.
});
```

Comment: Gotcha... so the real strength of '.each' is that fact that it's really 'looping' through the elements which allows you the ability to increment...?

Comment: @chrisb: Right, `.each` is an iterator that allows you to treat matched elements individually. If you don't need to differentiate between matched elements then there's no need for `.each`.

Comment: Thank you all so much. This has been great! You guys are fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same thing.

You would use `$.each`, though, when you also wanted to do something else to each of the elements that you are matching.